# Sabertooth 990fx audio drivers (Kubuntu)

Tags: drivers, sound, kubuntu, asus

Not sure if I'm right here but I have a very hardware specific question. Just installed Kubuntu 13.10 on my gaming rig yesterday (to play KSP on 64bit ;) ). And so far everything worked rather well (not a linux pro here).

However I've been having trouble with my sound. As I mentioned in the title I'm using the Sabertooth 990fx audio controller with a normal set of 2.1 speakers. In addition to that I have a front panel connected to the motherboard where I plug in my 3,5mm analoge headset.

In the system settings it displays me all sorts of audio output options, including some 5.1 and 7.1 (that shouldn't exist) but none of them in no configuration outputs anything on the speakers connected to the back.

In addition I can't find any sound drivers in the list of "additional drivers" that it sugests me to install (only two ATI graphics drivers).

Hope someone can help me with this. ASUS doesn't seem to have official linux drivers :C

Comment: post $ sudo lshw | grep -i audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a few more hours on it I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 where everything works splendetly. Yes I know that Linux is fully supported and yes I tried all audio outputs.

Also re-installing alsa 10 times didn't fix anything.

So yea. On Kubuntu 12.04 now (hardware support release) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2012-10-23-asus-sabertooth-990fx says that sabertooth-990fx is fully supported by linux. Your problem seems to be configuration related one. Try selecting each one of the audio output options and restarting. Make sure that your speaker plugged into the right jack.

PS : It will be more helpful if you provide the output of `aplay -l`, `cat /etc/asound.conf` and `cat ~/.asoundrc`

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall pulse audio and Alsa, open terminal and enter the following commands-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then restart PC and see if it works.